# Can I say "Similar functionalities to Tool B"?

Tags: grammar

I want to express

```
Tool A provides some functionalities.
The functionalities of Tool A are similar to those of Tool B.
```

Can I simplify the two sentences as

```
Tool A provides similar functionalities to Tool B
```

or

```
Tool A provides similar functionalities to those of Tool B
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are acceptable. The first sentence is more direct as it states simply and clearly that Tool A and Tool B have similar functionalities.

> Tool A provides similar functionalities to Tool B.

The second option is a little less clear, and a native speaker would not phrase it like that, but more like:

> The functionalities of Tool A are similar to those of Tool B.

That is, the *< properties >* of *< object 1 >* have *< relationship >* to *< properties >* of *< object 2 >*.

In forming the sentence with a comparison using *similar* the usage is *similar ... to*, or if using *same* the usage is *same ... as*.

Viz.

> Tool A provides similar functionalities to Tool B.

or, if Tool B has the same functionality as Tool A:

> Tool A provides the same functionalities as Tool B.

... although in the second case it would be expressed with singular *functionality*.

Answer (score -2):

A common expression would be:

> Tool A provides the similar functionalities as Tool B.

*as* there means just like *B.*

The whole sentence is

> Tool A provides the similar functionalities as Tool B *does*.

---

For those who think *'provides the similar functionalities...'* is grammatically incorrect:

A reference from [some *scholar* thesis.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6773/e0f9aabd4341dd014261b5bb86ad790caa28.pdf)

> However, because of the limited access to the PROSIT system within the time span of the thesis project, a customized application that ***provides the similar functionalities*** as PROSIT had to be developed. The application will have two main functions: download the software to and verify the software in the cab ECU.

Comment: In both of these statements, "provides the similar functionalities," is incorrect grammar. Omit "_the_" to form, "provides similar functionalities." The second statement also cannot contain "_does_." While common speech sometimes appends the second verb _does_ at the end of a sentence, it is grammatically incorrect and should be correctly written, "Tool A provides similar functionalities as Tool B." The use of "_as_" is acceptable as widespread use but correctly written should be _similar ... to_ or _same ... as_ rather than _similar ... as_.

Comment: *"provides the similar functionalities," is incorrect grammar. Omit "the" to form, "provides similar functionalities."*...reference please. @Mick

Comment: _from some scholar thesis_ is also grammatically incorrect. Correct would be _from some scholar's thesis_ or _from a scholarly thesis_. I note that the author of that thesis is also probably not a native English speaker so mistakes like that could be expected. A Google search for "_provides the similar functionalities_" returns "about 9 results" (in Google's words) including this page, while a search for "_provides similar functionalities_" returns "about 3260 results".

Comment: @Mick Ah, you depend on Google results! No words then! And, if *scholar thesis* is incorrect, I'm sure 'Public department' will also look down to you! :)

Comment: Only if they are higher than me :-)